# Angular 2/Typescript: Get value from [object Object]

Tags: angular, typescript, reflection, typescript2.0

I have an angular 2 web application that fires some events. On of the properties of event.target.parentNode looks like this. The nodeValue and value show [object Object]. How can I get the actual content of this object?

[image]

Edited to add code:

```js
pressed(event, item: someItem) {
        console.log(event);
  console.log(event.target.parentNode.attributes[1].value);
        console.log("pressed");
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid" [ngGrid]="{'max_cols': 3, 'auto_resize': true}">
        <sticky-note *ngFor="let item of items"
                     [stickyNote]="sNotes" class="grid-item" [(ngGridItem)]='item.config'
                     (onDragStop)="dragged(item)"  (press)="pressed($event, item)" (pressup)="pressedup($event, item)" #gItem> </sticky-note>
      
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can, it seems to have been turned into a string at some point. Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: Where does `ng-reflect-config` come from? What event is "fires some"?

Comment: Gunter, I believe ng-reglect-config is coming from [(ngGridItem)]. This is a directive from angular2-grid component that I am using for drag and drop. This fires events onDragStop and onDragStart.

What I have also done is, to enable touch I have integrated Hammer.js and I am handling press and pressup events. Now, on these events, I want to fire onDragStart and onDragStop events from angular2-grid. For this, I need the instance on ngGridItem. I am hoping that the nodeValue/value of ng-reflect-config will provide me this. Hence I need to know what is in there.